# Wireless connection not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I have a problem establishing wi-fi connection in Ubuntu. Wired connection is working fine (all updates installed), the problem is I can not connect to wireless. I can see a lot of networks around me, but I can not see my router. Sometimes I can see it, I try to connect but connection fails. I have also tried connecting to my hotspot, but no success. Other machines are using wi-fi with no problem. I am a newbie to Linux, so if anyone can guide me how to install drivers, etc. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Will you post the output of `lspci` the output of `sudo nm-tool` the output of `ifconfig -a` and the ouput of `dmesg | wlan`

Thanks,
tfrue

Comment: Welcome to AU. [Please use comments to ask for information or clarify a question or answer](http://askubuntu.com/about) in future. (Once you earn 50 reputation, you can comment on anybody's post.)

Comment: Ok, sounds like a plan to me!